# How to display a max, min, and average result from an array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, max, average, min

Basically I have to write a program that asks a user to name the amount of players on their football team, list their names and how many goals they have scored. The output should then be "the top player is..with a score of .. The average goals scored is.. The lowest goals scored is.."

We haven't really covered arrays properly yet, but I have started this question now and it will drive me crazy until I get it done. I know I am probably a good bit away from getting what I need but any point in the right direction would be really appreciated! P.S I know the last bit of my code is completely wrong I just don't know where to go from here. My code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of players");
    int amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    string[] names = new string[amount];
    int[] playerGoals = new int[amount];
    int result;
    string playerName;

    for (int i = 0; i < playerGoals.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a players name");
        playerName = Console.ReadLine();
        names[i] = playerName;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many goals they have score this season");
        result = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        playerGoals[i] = result;
    }

    int minimum = playerGoals.Min();
    int maximum = playerGoals.Max();
    double average = playerGoals.Average();

    Console.WriteLine("The top player is {0} with a score of {1}", maximum);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("The average goals scored is {0}", average);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("The lowest goal scored is {1}");

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: From the looks of it, it looks like you're already getting the minimum and maximum. I would guess your average is not giving you what you expect simply from integer truncation (that is, given 2 goals and 3 goals, you're getting 2 goals instead of 2.5); is that your problem? EDIT: nevermind, didn't realize that already handled that aspect. So what's the problem _specifically_?

Comment: What's your question? I guess you get `Exception` at `Console.WriteLine` right?

Comment: What's the input, average output, and what did you expected the average to be?

Comment: the problem specifically is I dont know how to get it to actually output the max score, lowest score, average score and highest scoring player. I have tried researching the answer but cant find it.

Comment: So when you are debugging and stepping through your code, `minimum`, `maximum` and `average` contain the right value?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some approaches you could take:

1. Look up the player with the max score

   ```
   string maxPlayer = names[Array.IndexOf(playerGoals, maximum)];
   ```
2. Calculate the max yourself in a loop (either as you're taking the inputs or afterward), in a way that you keep track of the player along with it.
3. Create a `PlayerStats` class so you have one array (`PlayerStats[]`) instead of two, and use [MoreLINQ's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) `MaxBy`. This would end up with the best code in my opinion, but is possibly more advanced than you're ready for (knowing how to do things manually is a good skill to have, although you don't always use it in the real world).

   ```
   var best = playerStats.MaxBy(x => x.Goals);
   Console.WriteLine("The top player is {0} with a score of {1}",
                     best.Name, best.Goals);

   public class PlayerStats
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Goals { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for your help guys, that is a bit to take in but I will go with it for the next while and try make sense of it! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Player
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int goals { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of players");
            int amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List<Player> _players = new List<Player>();
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                Player objPlayer = new Player();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a players name");
                objPlayer.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter how many goals they have score this season");
                objPlayer.goals  = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                _players.Add(objPlayer);

            }

            int maxgoals = _players.Max(t => t.goals);
            var maxplayer = _players.FirstOrDefault(t => t.goals == maxgoals).Name;

            int mingoals = _players.Min(t => t.goals);
            var minplayer = _players.FirstOrDefault(t => t.goals == maxgoals).Name;

            var average = _players.Sum(t=>t.goals)/amount;

            Console.WriteLine("The top player is {0} with a score of {1}", maxplayer, maxgoals);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("The bottom player is {0} with a score of {1}", minplayer, mingoals);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("The average goals scored is {0}", average);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Whoever down voted your answer didn't even have time to read your answer lol. Somebody is being quite sad indeed.